# yii2: custom only some buttons in actions columns (other ones by default)

Tags: gridview, action, yii2

I would like to overload only some buttons in action columns,
but when I try to do it, the default button does not work

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        (...)

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'headerOptions'=> ['style'=>'width: 70px;'],
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                    (...)
                },
                'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                    (...)
                }
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key) {
                if ($action === 'view') {
                    (...)
                }
                else if ($action === 'update') {
                    (...)
                }
            }
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Using the code above, the 'delete' action doesn't work,
the code generated is:

```
<a title="Elimina" aria-label="Elimina" data-confirm="...?" data-method="post" data-pjax="0">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
    </span>
</a>
```

So, "delete" action is not sent and index page is re-load,

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is causing the issue:

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key) {
    if ($action === 'view') {
        (...)
                }
    else if ($action === 'update') {
        (...)
    }
}
```

You did not specify url сreation for `delete` action button, that's why it does nothing when you click on it. Add condition into `urlCreator` callback for `delete` to generate url.

Comment: Therefore, anyway I have to generate the delete url by code and I cannot use the automatic generation of Yii, right?

Comment: Yes, if you specify `urlCreator` callback you need to handle url creation manually because it doesn't fallback to default implementation.